# Array is empty in delegate function

Tags: swift, uitableview, delegates, protocols

I just implemented this protocol delegate construct. But anything went wrong. I press the delete button in my custom UITableViewCell and I want to remove an item in my array. I reach the delegate function and I can print the id. But the array is empty (nil). What went wrong?

```
protocol KonfigDataDelegate: class {
    func deleteItem(id: UUID)
}

class MyClass {

    var Bezeichnung: Sting = ""
    ...
    
}

class ViewControllerKonfiguration: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, KonfigDataDelegate {
    
    var myArray: [MyClass] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...
        myArray = loadAnyDataInArray()
        print(myArray.count) --> 3 elements in array
        ...
    }    
    
    func deleteItem(id: UUID) {
        print("ID: \(id)") --> prints my id
        print(myArray.count) --> 0 - Why is my array empty?
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {        
        var cell: UITableViewCell
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tvcMahlzeit", for: indexPath) as! TVCKonfigMahlzeit
        (cell as! TVCKonfigMahlzeit).edBezeichnung.text = myArray[indexPath.row]
        (cell as! TVCKonfigMahlzeit).delegate = self

    }   
    
}

class TVCKonfigMahlzeit: UITableViewCell {

    var id: UUID?
    weak var delegate: KonfigDataDelegate?
       
    @IBAction func buttonDeletePresed(_ sender: Any) {
        var vc = ViewControllerKonfiguration()
        self.delegate = vc as KonfigDataDelegate
        delegate?.deleteItem(id: id!)
    }
 
}
```

Comment: Because it’s not the same instance that prints the values, viewDidLoad is called for the view controller you use in your storyboard while the empty array comes from the local variable you create in the method. You need to access your existing view controller rather creating one locally in buttonDeletePresed

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/dont-make-a-new-instance-by-mistake/

Answer (score -2):

When I remove these lines it works. I create here a new instance of ViewControllerKonfiguration and there the array is empty.

```
    @IBAction func buttonDeletePresed(_ sender: Any) {
        remove this ––> var vc = ViewControllerKonfiguration()
        remove this ––> self.delegate = vc as KonfigDataDelegate
        delegate?.deleteItem(id: id!)
    }
```